# Why TextView's margin not working in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, margin, android-constraintlayout

My id/ambient_check_text's marginStart/marginEnd not working, I tested in real device. It looks like below:

[image]

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ambient_title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha="0.80"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/vip_detail_activity_ic_pro"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/ambient_detail_title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <util.TopCropImageView
        android:id="@+id/ambient_permission_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ambient_detail_permission_bg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ambient_title_text"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.80"
        android:background="@drawable/ambient_detail_decibels_bg"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="@string/ambient_detail_decibels_for_sleep_25db"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ambient_permission_bg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ambient_permission_bg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ambient_quick_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ambient_detail_quick_view_bg"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/ambient_detail_quick_view"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ambient_permission_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ambient_check_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.80"
        android:text="12312313123123123123123123@string/ambient_detail_check_to_see"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ambient_quick_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ambient_permission_bg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ambient_permission_bg" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

UPDATE1:

My id/ambient_quick_view not working as I expected as well, as in some language it is 'quick view' or 'a long version of some language quick view', I tested in real device. (I think I actually expect wrap_content behave, and marginStart behave at the same time, maybe I should not use ContraintLayout.)

[image]

Comment: Change android:layout_width of ambient_check_text view to match_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

In `ConstraintLayout`, whenever we apply constraint, we need to work with `0dp`, if vertical (0dp to height) & if horizontal (0dp to width)

Comment: It's working, thank you. you mean, I must use 0dp in most case instead of wrap_content in ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Yes, I updated answer with last line for more clarification. You can accept answer if you get the understanding.

Comment: :-/ New problem, I add UPDATE1 to my question.

Comment: do the same, change its width to 0dp

Comment: If change to 0dp, ambient_quick_view's width will be 'PARENT_WIDTH-58-58'. But I expect "quick view"'s string char width:  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ambient_quick_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="58dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"

Comment: Do you expect the textview to occupy space as per the content and also it should not exceed margins?

Comment: @Kamal Yes, I think I want it behaves = wrap_content + marginStart (in ConstraintLayout)

Comment: Yes, for such cases. So, if it is solved. you can accept answer as well. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Because you applied `wrap_text` as textview's width. `wrap_content` takes as much width as required based on content even though you applied horizontal constraints.

Change it to `0dp`.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/ambient_check_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.80"
        android:text="12312313123123123123123123@string/ambient_detail_check_to_see"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/ambient_quick_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ambient_permission_bg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ambient_permission_bg" />
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. Clould you tell me why this happens, I'm newbie using ConstraintLayout. What's the diff between wrap_content and 0dp? and why it behave diff in RelativeLayout and ContraintLayout? thank you

Comment: match_parent works as well, I'm a little confused :/

Comment: 0dp means it will fill up the horizontal space based on the constraint you set at start and end.

Comment: match parent means it will fill up the space as identical as its parent view

Comment: You've applied start and end constraints (to tell the textview start end references). When you use wrap content, if the text is very small it will show at center point between start and end. As the text enlarges it will grow as much as parent views full width.

Comment: :-/ New problem, I add UPDATE1 to my question.

Comment: Hi, if you're still have difficulties, better wrap the textview inside framelayout. set 0dp with and constraints for framelayout. And keep textview as wrap_content. So that textview will behave as wrap_content also it will not go beyond margins